# Animating a mouth in 2D with blender 2.8

Tags: animation, modifiers, grease-pencil, timeline

I am trying to animate a mouth using the time offset modifier. Which, essentialy for all those who are used to doing 2D animation with other software, is a form of frame picker.

However, this is where my issue lies:

After...

- setting up the layer with different mouth key frames
- naming the layer lip sinc
- adding the time offset modifier whilst in object mode
- chosing the selected lip sinc layer within the modifier tab
- opening up the dope sheet

Everything seems to work up until I add keyframes that I spaceout for a significant amount of frames, for example 10 frames. For instance if I insert a key frame from the time offset modifier on frame 1 and add another one on frame 10, it will work. However when pressing play , the timeline will play every keyframe in between the two initial keyframe that I inserted in the time offset modifer.

This means that my time line will have those two keyframes that I selected on frame 1 and 10. But by the time the time cursor gets to frame 10 of my inserted keyframe, it will have played all the keyframes in between the two keyframes I have selected in the time offset modifier. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide screenshots to illustrate better your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I don't know why it's happening to me, while others seem to do it without trouble, but I tried to change the interpolation mode to constant, and it worked. 
Go to:
Editor type > Action editor 
right click > interpolation mode

Let me know if it worked for you!